# Serial communication between raspberry and laptop not giving right values

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial, rs232, ttl, python

I want to communicate between a Raspberry Pi 3 model B and a laptop using a USB to RS-232 cable and this RS-232 to 3.3V TTL converter via the serial module in Python:

[image]
GND is connected to board pin #6
3.3V is connected from board pin #2 to VCC
Rx is connected to board pin #10
Tx is connected to board pin #8

The code I'm executing in the Raspberry is the next one:

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=3.0)

port.write(b'hello')
```

And the code I'm executing in the laptop is the next one:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM11',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=1)

line = ser.read_until()
print(line)
```

The problem is that in the laptop I receive the next sequence on bytes, and those change depending on an unknown factor:

- b'\xd0)\xe1\xd3\xf7'
- b'\xd0+\x13\xd7\xf7'
- b'\xd0+\xe3\xe1\xf9\xff'
- b'\xd0+\xe1\xe1\xf3'

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? Any help is really appreciated

**EDIT: ESD discharge magically solved this issue (I think)**
I was checking if I made the right connections in the Raspberry Pi and accidentally touched some of the pins in the board and received a shock. I really feared that this damaged the Raspberry, but everything seemed ok. After this event I run the program once again and received the right bits every time. I think that this is scary, especially because I didn't intended to damage my board with an ESD. 
Is this assumption true? I didn't modify anything to any program O_O

Comment: How about running some off-the-shelf serial terminal (Putty?) on your laptop instead of this code?

Comment: That will be PuTTY - as in TeleTYpe. Good idea. That will show whether or not there is a problem at the transmit end.

Comment: Have you disabled the serial console on your Raspberry Pi? It's on ttyAMA0. Check /boot/cmdline.txt

Comment: Or better yet, first *enable* the serial console and make sure you can talk to that with putty.  And before doing that, conduct a *loopback test* of just the serial cable without the pi, where you see that characters typed on the terminal program only show up (or show up twice) only when you jumper pin 2 to 3 of the 9-pin connector, or the RXD to the TXD of the voltage adapter.  Right now you just have too many moving parts and no idea where the problem is.  Also it would be easier to use a USB<>3v3 UART cable rather than go through the extra step of converting to RS232 and back.

Comment: @Janka I've already checked that

Comment: @Transistor I'm using Termite as the serial interface

Comment: Sounds more likely that you have flaky connections (missing ground?) and fixed that.  Or else you had some odd software state, perhaps some background daemon running like brltty which was fighting you for the port.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, maybe, I first though that the cables were the guilty ones. The important thing is that it works now :D

Comment: That doesn't mean it will work tomorrow, however...  Either you had a temporary issue which has been corrected, or you still have a real issue and are only being lucky (or from a debugging perspective, unlucky) not to be seeing it at the moment.